# Idris dependent records with interface constraint on Type Constructor parameter

Tags: idris, type-constraints

Is it possible to have interface constraints on a parameter to a type constructor of a dependent record in idris?
Say I have an interface  `Show : Type -> Type`. Now I need to place a constraint on the following dependent record:

```
record Source s where
   constructor MkSource
   initial : s
```

I need to place a constraint on the parameter `s`so that it should always be a instance of `Show`. How to achieve this?

Comment: By "always an instance of `Show`" do you mean there should exist a witness `ss : Show s` ? If yes, why not just add another field to `Source` of type `Show s`?

Comment: Can you please include the actual definition of the `Show` interface in your question (ie using the keywords `interface` and `where`).

Answer (score 2):

Idris is under heavy development but according to this recent email to the idris group the record syntax does currently not support constraining types with an interface:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idris-lang/HMeTylslyFc

You will need to use data type syntax instead, e.g.

```
module Main

data Source: Type -> Type where
    MkSource: Show s => s -> Source s


x: Source Int
x = MkSource 3

showSource: Source s -> String
showSource  (MkSource x) = show $ x

testMe: (showSource $ Main.x = "3")
testMe = Refl
```

Comment: do you know if this answer is still valid?

Comment: @Saintali See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
record a {auto eq : Eq a} where
  constructor MkThing
  target : Int
  value : a
```

Source: [Discord](https://discord.com/channels/827106007712661524/838742669953204224/1019841834136109096)